# hastily took up a job but I dont enjoy it for a reason

Tags: quitting

I am currently working as a technical writer in a medium sized company.

I have done my MBA in HR and prior to that I've done my btech. I landed up into this job because of the personal crisis. Post my MBA both my parents fell sick and I had to support them. It was in the year 2015 on 23rd March I took this job. Imagine I completed my MBA in June 14' and had to wait this long to join a job.

I was really desperate to work and my passion for writing has fueled it. But now I feel that I'm going nowhere. No challenges, no awards and no motivation and my education doesn't even match the job role. There is no sense of satisfaction at all. Everything is saturated, I felt the same after a year but my marriage leave for a month has made me come out of this monotony. I really don't know what to do.

I should have given a thought before taking up the job, but I didn't. Please help me and suggest me.

Answer (score 3):

There's no big state secret here. If you don't like your job, find a new job that you like better.

This time there is no rush, you have a stable income, so you can do better at picking the job that fits you.

Start by writing your CV, look out for jobs that interest you and start to apply. Don't give notice until you have *signed the written contract*. Then go and be happy about it.

Comment: Since you're searching with no rush, I'd also recommend being careful in selecting a new job, since leaving two jobs in a row after a short time gives the impression that you are a job hopper.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure there's no challenge or satisfaction in this job, you should start looking for other jobs. There's a few things you could do:

- Check out with your boss if things can be improved (for the time you'll still be there).
- Find out what you want. Go to a career/job coach if you feel confused.
- Look around on LinkedIn (or create an account if you don't have one).
- Orientate for other jobs, look for positions that you find interesting.
- Start applying and take some time to think about it.